# how to show the months between two dates in db2

Tags: db2

I have a table db2admin.shdl_dtl in which there are two columns for the date-

startdate
enddate

from these two date columns I want to show months between two dates

i.e. startdate = '2015-01-05' and enddate = '2015-04-20' then output of the query should come like this-

Output- jan, feb, mar, apr

Comment: What did you try so far? Have you looked at the function `MONTHNAME` already?

Comment: What if there are years between the two dates? Do you want a single row result or one row per month? Some more details csan be helpful so we do not have to "guess"....

Comment: You want "jan, feb, mar, apr" as a comma separated value in one row?  Or did you want "jan", "feb", "mar" and "apr" as single values in different rows?

Answer (score 1):

```
with cte (diffmonths,monthdiff) as 
(select date(startdate ) as diffmonths,0 from sysibm.sysdummy1
 union all
 select date(diffmonths) + 1 month as diffmonths,month(diffmonths) from cte   
 where diffmonths<=(date(enddate)) )
 select * from cte where MONTHDIFF >0
```